# Is it still possible to set the sample rate programatically in Google Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have an app that is using Google Analytics through Google Play Services for Android. The app is setup to track a smaller group of users by setting the sample rate. I have done this using:

```
mTracker.setSampleRate(20.0d);
```

As in the documentation for Google Analytics Android.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced

This has worked our nicely for me in the past, but recently I upgraded to Google Play Services ***com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0***. Since then the number of users have increased dramatically, but only in the analytics. Is there a problem with the sample rate in the new version?

Best regards,
Kalle

Comment: To avoid reporting inconsistencies, each of your app views (profiles) should contain data collected at the same sampling rate. If different versions of your app use different sampling rates, you'll need to configure view (profile) filters using the app version dimension to keep the data from each version of your app separate.